# FFmpeg-php installation on cpanel server with CentOS7

Tags: php, ffmpeg, cpanel, centos7, ffmpeg-php

I installed ffmpeg via below commands but unable to install FFmpeg-php on cpanel server with CentOS7.

Checked articles and found very old version. Please anyone can assist with new FFmpeg-php version and installation steps.

rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro

rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm

yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel -y

Regards,

Mel

Comment: Why are you "unable to install FFmpeg-php", are you getting an error message?

Comment: https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/ffmpeg-php-ffmpeg-centos-6-7/